# regular expression for objective c to check consecutive incremental number

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex

I want to check if the number pin user entered is too simple. 3 cases would fail, repeating numbers, like "1111"; increasing ones like "1234"; decreasing ones like "4321". Is there a regex which could check these restrictions?

Comment: Repeating can be checked with `@"([0-9])\\1\\1\\1"`

Comment: Regex is for text processing; it doesn't recognize numbers as numbers so it can't do any math operations like -1 or 'one less than'.  I'd look into other methods.  Edit: Also, I can understand disallowing four repeating numbers, but disallowing all sequential numbers like 7654 is going to greatly reduce your keyspace and actually make it easier for someone to brute force the PIN.

Comment: @rmaddy thanks I'll do it this way

Comment: @paul.abbott.wa.us Yes you are right. Actually I just learnt this from ios 7's password check, which will remind you that it's a weak password but allow you to continue with this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex can match specific text pattern but it can't understand its context..Yes you want to check for increasing numbers but there's no such thing as increasing pattern in regex.

You can check for repeated numbers using `^(\d)\1+$`

But to check for increasing,decreasing numbers you would have to `parse` the `string` to `int` and check if they are in increasing or decreasing order manually using the `%`,`/` operations